# In $\mathbb{R}$, find the minimal connected subset containing $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

In $\mathbb{R}$, find the minimal connected subset containing $\mathbb{N}$.

I think the answer is $[1,\infty)$. Am I correct?

Comment: Are you sure you should not be finding the minimal one? The maximal one is clearly the entire set (as this is connected).

Comment: Sorry for that. It is minimal connected subset.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Yes you're right. If $U$ is a connected subset containing $\mathbb N$ and $x\in [1,\infty)\setminus U$, then $(-\infty,x)\cap U$ and $(x,\infty) \cap U$ disconnect $U$. Hence $[1,\infty)\subset U$.

Comment: Assuming, as seems virtually certain, that by $\Bbb N$ you mean $\Bbb Z^+$, the set of positive integers, then you’re right. If by $\Bbb N$ you mean the set of natural numbers, which for a great many of us includes $0$, then of course you want $[0,\to)$ rather than $[1,\to)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean *minimal* conntected subset, then you are right, the maximal connected subset is of course $\mathbf R$, as $\mathbf R$ is connected and there is no larger subset than the whole set.